# Как строить график с учетом времени(день, часы, минуты)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблема с выводом графика с учетом времени(день, часы, минуты), по дате все нормально работает. Использую библиотеки **chartist.js**, **moment.js** демо: [График](http://jsfiddle.net/3uL7zu4o/151/)

```js
var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  series: [
    {
      name: 'series-1',
      data: [
        {x: new Date('September 1, 2016 00:00:00'), y: 346.2},
        {x: new Date('September 1, 2016 11:00:00'), y: 346.9},
        {x: new Date('September 6, 2016 12:00:00'), y: 346.9},
        {x: new Date('September 12, 2016 05:00:00'), y: 346.9},
        {x: new Date('September 12, 2016 22:00:00'), y: 346.9},
        {x: new Date('September 18, 2016 06:10:00'), y: 347.8},
        {x: new Date('September 18, 2016 23:10:00'), y: 346.9},
        {x: new Date('September 24, 2016 10:00:00'), y: 345.9},
        {x: new Date('September 30, 2016 03:00:00'), y: 347.8},
        {x: new Date('September 30, 2016 21:00:00'), y: 346.9}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'series-2',
      data: [
        {x: new Date('September 1, 2016 00:00:00'), y: 342.2},
        {x: new Date('September 1, 2016 22:40:00'), y: 342.9},
        {x: new Date('September 6, 2016 12:00:00'), y: 342.9},
        {x: new Date('September 12, 2016 05:00:00'), y: 342.9},
        {x: new Date('September 12, 2016 22:00:00'), y: 342.9},
        {x: new Date('September 18, 2016 06:10:00'), y: 343.8},
        {x: new Date('September 18, 2016 23:10:00'), y: 342.9},
        {x: new Date('September 24, 2016 10:00:00'), y: 341.9},
        {x: new Date('September 30, 2016 03:00:00'), y: 343.8},
        {x: new Date('September 30, 2016 21:00:00'), y: 342.9}
      ]
    }
  ]
}, {

  axisY: {
    type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
    ticks:[340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350],
    low: 340,
    high: 350,
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
      return (value) + 'тг.';
    }
  },
  axisX: {
    type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
    divisor: 6,
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
      return moment(value).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    }
  },
  fullWidth: true,
  lineSmooth: false,
  height:'500px',
  chartPadding: {
    left: 20
  }
});
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
  if(data.type === 'point') {
    var circle = new Chartist.Svg('circle', {
      cx: [data.x], cy:[data.y], r:[5],
    }, 'ct-circle');
    data.element.replace(circle);
  }
});
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.